# Line widths of Ne spectral lamp

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy

I need to know the line widths (FWHM) of spectral lines of a Ne spectral lamp. There is a lot of [information about the lines' center](https://www.physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/neontable2.htm) on the internet, but I couldn't find anything relevant or measurements on the FWHM of these lines. Is there any site/references that you could suggest so I can find these values? I'm particularly interested in the 585.249 nm line.

Comment: (+1) Good question! I see that line all the time using my homemade echelle spectrographs. For example, look at the last figure [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164168/79678). That Ne line is near the upper right and is the brightest yellow line in the over-exposed echellogram. But my best resolution to date is 0.067 nm FWHM and I think the line is narrower than that. If I find a reference for that line width, in any Ne spectral lamp or hollow cathode lamp, I will comment or answer here. I hope someone here knows the answer!

Comment: This has some spectral line width information for several neon lines: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/N-Konjevic/publication/264315671_Ne_I_spectral_line_shapes_in_Grimm_type_glow_discharge/links/54b1667f0cf220c63ccf9db6/Ne-I-spectral-line-shapes-in-Grimm-type-glow-discharge.pdf. Not the specific line you want and the various broadening mechanisms always complicate matters.

Comment: Thank you! Your answers have been really helpful

Comment: This reference seems to be the best available: E.B. Saloman, Craig J. Sansonetti, Wavelengths, Energy Level Classifications, and Energy Levels for the Spectrum of Neutral Neon, J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data, Vol. 33, No. 4, 2004. It is freely available on the web.